# how to upgrade node to 16 on ARM mac with macos 12.4

Tags: node.js, macos

I have node v15.10.0 installed. I dont know how it was installed.
I found [this](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/update-node-js-version) article on how to update node.  For mac it recommends using the official binary installer, which I did.  It says the new version should overwrite the old version.
After installation, if I open a new terminal and do node --version, it stills says 15.10.0

The question is, how do I fully delete the old version, and install the new?

My path looks like this:
/Users/xx/.nvm/versions/node/v15.10.0/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/opt/apache-maven/bin

I presume I could hack the path using a shell script, but is there a better way?  Why did the installer not do this for me?

If we have to hack the path (for each user), which is the correct file? I see there is a **.bashrc** and a **.zprofile** in my home dir.  They are not linked, but they have identical content, which is bazare, and they do not contain code to add /Users/xx/.nvm/versions/node/v15.10.0/bin to the path, so this must be set outside of either file?

I cant see 15 path in /etc/paths either.

I have no idea what shell you get in Mac now a days, but if I do ps -ef I see  it mentions both bash and zsh.

Presumably I need to change the path on both ?

Comment: Well, you've clearly used `nvm` to install 15.x – maybe google for nvm-specific removal instructions?

Comment: (Also, remember there's also `.zshrc` and `.zlogin` and `.bashrc`...)

Answer (score 1):

if you have nvm installed, the best way is :

```
nvm install 16
```

To switch between installed node version:

```
nvm use 16
```

To set default node version:

```
nvm alias default 16
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @AKX this was the solution:

nvm uninstall 15.10.0

Now I see v16.